# How to Change the Font of the Windows 8 Apps?

Tags: windows-8

while reading longer articles i always prefer Georgia. In Wikipedia App for Windows 8 the fonts are sans-serif. Is there any way through which I can change the default font of the Windows 8 Apps?

Answer (score 0):

[Take ownership](http://www.intowindows.com/take-ownership-of-files-and-folders-in-windows-8/) of the hidden folder+all files (C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\WikimediaFoundation.Wikipedia_1.0.0.28_neutral__54ggd3ev8bvz6) and edit the CSS files to change the size and font type.